# Deploying site to IIS server

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7, publishing

I am developing a MVC site in VS 2013 using 4.6.1 Framework. I need to deploy the site to a Remote desktop IIS server.

But after deploying, The site responds with 503 error

Steps I followed:
Created a application pool with version 4.0 
To verify if IIS has 4.6.1 installed. 
Location: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full and checked Release Data (has value 394271)
Created a new site and converted it into an application.
Created a new virtual directory and pasted the code from project into it (publish setup done).

Problem: 
When I try to access the site, It responds back with 503 and the app pool stops. I have disabled the App pool-> advanced setting ->Rapid-Fail protection -> Enabled to false
But the app pool seems to stop still.

My error log Reason is AppOffline. I have gone through the code, (which when run on the local dev machine works great) but I am not sure how to identify the cause of the problem.

What are the possible causes for the above problem on IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150952/what-possibilities-can-cause-service-unavailable-503-error).

Your web pages are served by an application pool. If you disable/stop the application pool, and anyone tries to browse the application, you will get a Service Unavailable. It can happen due to many reasons,

1. Your application may have crashed [check the event viewer and see if
   you can find event logs in your Application/System log]
2. Your application may be crashing very frequently. If an app pool
   crashes for 5 times in 5 minutes [check your application pool
   settings for rapid fail], your application pool is disabled by IIS
   and you will end up getting this message.

In either case, the issue is that your worker process is failing and you should troubleshoot it from crash perspective.

Check [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rahulso/2006/03/01/what-is-a-crash-technically-in-asp-net-and-what-to-do-if-it-happens/) and [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2010/02/17/a-not-so-common-root-cause-for-503-service-unavailable/).

Comment: Thanks Bko, Its was due to point two. I found the crash was caused due to access set for the apppool created. When I updated it it started working.